# C UNIX: how to assign a new signal handler

Tags: c, unix, signals

I have a signal handler where I set ctrl+z/SIGTSTP to just be detected by the program.  But when I want to change the signal handler of ctrl+z/SIGTSTP to its default behavior in the child process, the ctrl+z doesn't change.  Is there a proper to change signal handlers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void handler(int sig_num)
{
    printf("detected %d\n",sig_num);
}

int main()
{
    int x; 
    signal(SIGTSTP,handler);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {  
        signal(SIGTSTP,SIG_DFL);
        printf("in child process \n");
        while(1);
    }
    else if(pid > 0)
    {
        printf("running parent\n");
        printf("waiting for my child to run\n");
        wait(&x);
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why do you think the signal is sent to child at all? You don't seem to forward it...

Comment: signal() returns a pointer to the current signal handler.  so save that pointer, let the child restore the pointer

Comment: @Valeri Atamaniouk what do you mean by forward it? sorry I'm not too familiar with system calls.

Comment: this code fails to handle the 'pid <0' case, where the call to 'fork()' had failed.  The line: 'exit(0)' is unnecessary, clutters the code, and should be eliminated

Comment: this line: 'while(1);' results in the child NEVER exiting, so the wait() call in the parent NEVER returns, so the program will 'seem' to hang forever.  If the parent is forcefully killed, then the child will become a zombie, that may be difficult to eliminate without a re-boot of the system.

Comment: @killerkev the console will send signal to parent. which would block it. try to send signal to child using `kill` command directly. by using child's pid.